# JGit log strange behavior after merge

Tags: git-merge, jgit, git-log

Found a strange behavior (bug?) in a log command.

The below test creates a repo, creates a branch, does some commits either to the created branch and to master, then merges master to the created branch. After merge it tries to calculate the number of commits between the branch and master. Because master has been already merged -- the branch is not behind the master, i.e. corresponding commit count should be 0.

```java
public class JGitBugTest {

  @Rule
  public TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

  @Test
  public void testJGitLogBug() throws Exception {
    final String BRANCH_NAME = "TST-2";
    final String MASTER_BRANCH_NAME = Constants.MASTER;
    File folder = tempFolder.newFolder();
    // Create a Git repository
    Git api = Git.init().setBare( false ).setDirectory( folder ).call();
    Repository repository = api.getRepository();
    // Add an initial commit
    api.commit().setMessage( "Initial commit" ).call();
    // Create a new branch and add some commits to it
    api.checkout().setCreateBranch( true ).setName( BRANCH_NAME ).call();
    api.commit().setMessage( "TST-2 Added files 1" ).call();
    // Add some commits to master branch too
    api.checkout().setName( MASTER_BRANCH_NAME ).call();
    api.commit().setMessage( "TST-1 Added files 1" ).call();
    api.commit().setMessage( "TST-1 Added files 2" ).call();
    // If this delay is commented out -- test fails and
    // 'behind' is equal to "the number of commits to master - 1".
//     Thread.sleep(1000);
    // Checkout the branch and merge master to it
    api.checkout().setName( BRANCH_NAME ).call();
    api.merge()
      .include( repository.resolve( MASTER_BRANCH_NAME ) )
      .setStrategy( MergeStrategy.RECURSIVE )
      .call()
      .getNewHead()
      .name();
    // Calculate the number of commits the branch behind of the master
    // It should be zero because we have merged master into the branch already.
    Iterable<RevCommit> iterable = api.log()
      .add( repository.resolve( MASTER_BRANCH_NAME ) )
      .not( repository.resolve( BRANCH_NAME ) )
      .call();
    int behind = 0;
    for( RevCommit commit : iterable ) {
      behind++;
    }
    Assert.assertEquals( 0, behind );
  }
}
```

The above test fails, `behind` yields the number of commits in the master minus 1.

Moreover, if 'sleep' in line 43 is uncommented -- the bug will go away, and 'behind' is equal to 0.

What do I do wrong?  Is it a bug in JGit library or in my code?

Comment: The corresponding bug in the JGit tracker -- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=501211

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running the code on Windows, I can reproduce what you describe.

This looks like a bug in JGit to me. I recommend to [open a bugzilla](https://eclipse.org/jgit/support/) or post your findings to the [mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/jgit-dev).

Comment: Thank you.
I've already posted it on the JGit forum:
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1081085/